# Test project cannot find objects in the project it is testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and created a bunch of unit tests.

Here is an example:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\\Users\\Employee\\Documents\\Code Spaces\\shopvote2\\trunk\\Web", "/Web")]
    [UrlToTest("http://localhost/Web")]
    public void GetUserDetailsTest()
    {
        api_Accessor target = new api_Accessor(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        string username = string.Empty; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        string passhash = string.Empty; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        int requestID = 0; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        ShoppingRequestDetailsData[] expected = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        ShoppingRequestDetailsData[] actual;
        actual = target.GetUserDetails(username, passhash, requestID);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
    }
```

The problem is, it says:

The type or namespace name 'ShoppingRequestDetailsData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Cannot implicitly convert type 'ShoppingWithFriends.ShoppingRequestDetailsData[]' to 'ShoppingRequestDetailsData[]'

It picks up the Namespace that it's from, and I can run the tests that don't require custom classes. It's only these that are causing me problems.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `ShoppingRequestDetailsData` public?

Comment: Yeah, that class is public and so are all my classes im trying to access

Comment: “are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few things to check:

First, I would double-check the reference in your project -- is it a project reference or an assembly reference?  If it's an assembly reference, are you sure that it's pointing at the right version of the file?  (e.g. if you renamed directories, maybe it's pointing at the old directory).  To be sure, use a tool like Reflector to examine the assembly directly and make sure the type is there in the right namespace.

Second, I'm not sure if this is your problem but I had a similar issue where a namespace was not found even though there was a project reference in the same solution, types were public, etc..

It turned out that I needed to change the "Target Framework" to be ".NET Framework 4" instead of ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile". I didn't bother figuring out why this resulted in an "unknown namespace" error, but it solved my problem.

Just a couple things to check, hope it helps...

John

Comment: For those who run into the same problem. In my case, the test project had a different target framework than the referenced project. In that case, you don't get a clear error message. VS just tells you that it couldnt find the referenced dll.

Comment: this worked for me, syncing the target framework of the test project to be the same on the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout class access modifier. It should be public

Comment: `Yeah, that class is public and so are all my classes im trying to access`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).